# How can I put a border in a symbol layer with SDF image?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have this code. I need put a border in this symbol, but I don't know, how to do that. Can someone help me?

```
> const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
>       style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v11",
>       container: "map",
>       center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
>       zoom: 9, // starting zoom
>     });
>     map.on("load", () => {
>       if (!map.hasImage("i_circle_svg")) {
>         const img = new Image(145, 145);
>         img.src = "icons/i_circle_svg.svg";
>         img.onload = () =>
>           map.addImage("i_circle_svg", img, {
>             sdf: true,
>           });
>       }
>       map.addSource("source-teste", {
>         type: "geojson",
>         data: {
>           type: "Feature",
>           geometry: {
>             type: "Point",
>             coordinates: [-74.5, 40],
>           },
>           properties: {
>             title: "Mapbox DC",
>             "marker-symbol": "monument",
>           },
>         },
>       });
>       map.addLayer({
>         id: "HarvestPanelWeightLayer",
>         type: "symbol",
>         source: "source-teste",
>         paint: {
>           "icon-color": ["get","value"],
>         },
>         layout: {
>           "icon-image": "i_circle_svg",
>         },
>       });
>     });
```

I tried to put a icon-halo but it doesn't work very well

Answer (score 0):

You're providing an SVG file. You should add the border to the SVG file.

Comment: This is an sdf image, in this format when painting the icon it paints over the icon and removes the svg border